# How can i initiate a Grails Domain Class by using others Domain object

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have tow domain

```
class Book {

   String name
   Long id
}

class BookRef {

   String name
   Long id
   String refId
}
```

In `Book` table, I stored data like `id=1`, `name='Java'`.
Now I can initiate `BookRef` by getting `Book` like bellow

```
def book = Book.get(1)

def bookref = new BookRef()
bookref.id = book.id
bookref.name = book.name
bookref.refId = '1'
bookref.save()
```

But I want to initiate the `bookref` object by using the `book` object like `params` binding not by binding each individual properties.

For now, I have now used the property to property initialization but in a domain with various properties, it's time-consuming.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Book book = Book.get(1)

// Option 1
BookRef bookref = new BookRef(book.properties)
bookref.refId = '1'
bookref.save()

// Option 2
BookRef bookref = new BookRef()
bookref.properties = book.properties
bookref.refId = '1'
bookref.save()
```

Basically, in Grails, any `domainInstance.properties` gives you a map of all the domain fields.

**Please note**, this approach is good for primitive types like `String`, `boolean`, `int`, `Long` etc but Grails might throw an exception when the domain has collections, one-to-many or has-many relationship fields.

Comment: Dear Shashank ,
thanks for you answer.
 I have now used the property to property initialization but in a domain with huge properties, it's time-consuming.

have any other way to initiate the same properties of the two domains.

Comment: That's what I answered, Shishir. You can use `.properties` and bind it to the different domain (as long as fields are the same).